# Why there are two different ways to chain an Exception in Java ? Which is better for what cases?

Tags: java, exception

These are the two ways that we can do exception chaining :

```
Throwable initCause(Throwable)
Throwable(Throwable)
```

I think the second one is more elegant and more widely used . Then why is that some standard exceptions in the Java core library actually lack a chain aware constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what the javodoc says

> There are many advantages to unifying all of these facilities. Chief
>   among them are: (1) We guarantee that anyone who wants to record the
>   fact that one exception caused another can do so, regardless of what
>   the exceptions are. (2) By providing a common API to record the fact
>   that one exception caused another, we ease this task, making it more
>   likely that programmers will take the trouble to do it. (3) By
>   providing a common API to access causative exceptions, we greatly
>   increase the likelihood that this information will be made available
>   to those who need it. In fact, the proposed mechanism prints entire
>   "causal chain" as part of the standard stack backtrace, ensuring that
>   preexisting programs will provide this information with no additional
>   effort on the part of their authors.
>
> To address these issues, we have added two new methods to Throwable,
>   getCause() and initCause(Throwable), and two new constructors,
>   Throwable(Throwable) and Throwable(String, Throwable). Other "general
>   purpose" exception classes (like Exception, RunTimeException and
>   Error) have been similarly outfitted with (Throwable) and (String,
>   Throwable) constructors. However, even exceptions without such
>   constructors will be usable as "wrapped exceptions" via the initCause
>   method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/chained-exceptions.html